# change IsolatedStorage location

Tags: c#, isolatedstorage

Is there a way to change location of IsolatedStorage files? I am using .NET 3.5sp1 and I write my application in C#

I would like to change its location to `D:\TempDir`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe it is no. I think it's operating system + user dependent on the exact location your files end up.

If you could start sticking files anywhere, it wouldn't be very isolated and would kinda defeat the point of having application local storage.

Answer (score 0):

No, but you change the Isolated store, to different the predefined locations by supplying the parameter called IsolatedStorageScope when accessing the store:

C#
`IsolatedStorageFile.GetStore(IsolatedStorageScope.User)`

User scope: %LOCALAPPDATA%\IsolatedStorage
User Roaming scope: %APPDATA%\IsolatedStorage
Machine scope: %PROGRAMDATA%\IsolatedStorage\

[More info or documentation or older windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/isolated-storage)